# iPhone CABasicAnimation - where is are the new bounds set after the transform.scale

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-animation

I am using the following code to dump the before and after state of bounds for layer & presentation layer of a view that I am animating. I don't see any change - looks like I am missing something in terms of my understanding - have already read the CA programming guide couple of times but to no avail. Any guidance will be appreciated

`- (void) shrink{
    [Dumper dumpRect:@"BEFORE layer bounds" :[iv.layer bounds]];
    [Dumper dumpRect:@"BEFORE p-layer bounds" :[iv.layer.presentationLayer bounds]];`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
      CABasicAnimation *scaleAnim = [CABasicAnimatianimationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];

        scaleAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
        scaleAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];

    scaleAnim.autoreverses=NO;
    [scaleAnim setDuration:1];
    // these need to be invoked to retain the scaled version
    scaleAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [scaleAnim setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];

    [iv.layer addAnimation:scaleAnim forKey:@"scale"];

}completion:^(BOOL finished){

    NSLog(@"Animation done - %d",finished);
    [Dumper dumpRect:@"AFTER layer bounds" :[iv.layer bounds]];
    [Dumper dumpRect:@"AFTER p-layer bounds" :[iv.layer.presentationLayer bounds]];

}];
```

}

On running this code - I get the following:
BEFORE layer bounds - Rect x=0.000000 y=0.000000 w=100.000000 h=200.000000
BEFORE p-layer bounds - Rect x=0.000000 y=0.000000 w=100.000000 h=200.000000
Animation done - 1
AFTER layer bounds - Rect x=0.000000 y=0.000000 w=100.000000 h=200.000000
AFTER p-layer bounds - Rect x=0.000000 y=0.000000 w=100.000000 h=200.000000

So no change between before & after ?

Even with the "transform.translation" transformation, I am observing the same behavior.

I need the final bounds so that I can set the UIView i.e., iv to be set with the appropriate frame value.

Related question is that - I understand that when the layer is animated its just the drawing that is done but the underlying view is still set with the original frame- what is the right way to set the UIView frame.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have put that code in the `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration` method. You either use `CABasicAnimation` if you want only to animate something, or use `animateWithDuration` if you want to actually change something and want it to be animated. For example, if you want to change the frame animated, you write:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 100);
    iv.frame = newFrame;
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // Code to be executed after the animation
}];
```

This will change your frame, and it will be animated. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response - the code you provided worked perfectly.

I also want to try the CABasicAnimation. Code with CABasicAnimation below I have put together does animate the view but as before the final frame values for layer,presentation-layer stays unchanged....so the animation is drawn as part of the animation but the layer (& presentation layer) values do not reflect it?

Please guide ... TIA

Comment: Ok - finally found the problem (feel like kicking myself in the behind :-). Moved the "after dump calls" to the delegate method and voila the p-layer has the right values for the frame.

- (void)animationDidStop:(CABasicAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"animationDidStop");
    [Dumper dumpRect:@"AFTER layer frame" :[iv.layer frame]];
    [Dumper dumpRect:@"AFTER p-layer frame" :[iv.layer.presentationLayer frame]];
    [Dumper dumpRect:@"AFTER iv frame" :iv.layer.frame];
}